# Controller's length issue in TabBar + BottomBarNavigation scenario

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to build an app which uses a TabBar and a BottomBarNavigation.

I tried to manage the length of the DefaultTabController in several ways, but I keep having an error only when I go from index 2 to index 1 :

> Controller's length property (3) does not match the flutter: number of tab elements (2) present in TabBar's tabs property.

My code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './activites.dart';
import './evenements.dart';
import './offres_promos.dart';

class PrivesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => PrivesPageState();
}

class PrivesPageState extends State<PrivesPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  int _index;
  int _length;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _index = 0;
    _length = 3;
  }

  Widget _buildTabBar() {
    Widget _content;
    if (_index == 0) {
      _content = TabBar(tabs: <Tab>[
        Tab(text: "Tab 1 - index 0"),
        Tab(text: "Tab 2 - index 0"),
        Tab(text: "Tab 3 - index 0"),
      ]);
    } else if (_index == 1) {
      _content = TabBar(tabs: <Tab>[
        Tab(text: "Tab 1 - index 1"),
        Tab(text: "Tab 2 - index 1"),
      ]);
    } else if (_index == 2) {
      _content = null;
    }
    return _content;
  }

  Widget _buildTabBarView() {
    Widget _content;
    if (_index == 0) {
      _content = TabBarView(children: <Widget>[
        Page1(),
        Page2(),
        Page3(),
      ]);
    } else if (_index == 1) {
      _content = TabBarView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Page1(),
          Page2(),
        ],
      );
    } else if (_index == 2) {
      _content = TabBarView(
        children: <Widget>[
        ],
      );
    }
    return _content;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Index ' + this._index.toString());
    print('length ' + this._length.toString());
    return DefaultTabController(
        length: _length,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Home"),
            bottom: _buildTabBar(),
          ),
          body: _buildTabBarView(),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              currentIndex: _index,
              onTap: (int _index) {
                int l;
                if (_index == 0) {
                  l = 3;
                } else if (_index == 1) {
                  l = 2;
                } else if (_index == 2) {
                  l = 0;
                }
                setState(() {
                  this._length = l;
                  this._index = _index;
                });
              },
              items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.my_location),
                  title: Text("Around me"),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                  title: Text("My city"),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.people),
                  title: Text("My account"),
                ),
              ]),
        ));
  }
}
```

I also tried to correct the issue using the TabBarController to set the length in the initState method but it does not work either.

```
TabController _controller;
  int _index;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = new TabController(length: _length, vsync: this);
    _index = 0;
  }
```

I think I may not have find the right way to accomplish this but it is the only way that got so far in the development of this solution.

Can you please help me correcting my code or build this in another way.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You are changing the tab bar length but not updating the controller's one. Update it accordingly by adding it to your `setState` for example.

```
  setState(() {
                  this._length = l;
                  this._controller = new TabController(length: _length, vsync: this);
                  this._index = _index;
                });
```

Note : Use a `TickerProviderStateMixin` instead of a `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` in your class

Comment: It returns that error: flutter:EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE
flutter: The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
flutter: PrivesPagesState is a SingleTickerProviderStateMixin but multiple tickers were created.
flutter: A SingleTickerProviderStateMixin can only be used as a TickerProvider once. If a State is used for
flutter: multiple AnimationController objects, or if it is passed to other objects and those objects might
flutter: use it more than one time in total, then instead of mixing in a SingleTickerProviderStateMixin, use
flutter: a regular TickerProviderStateMixin.

Comment: Use a `TickerProviderStateMixin` instead of a single ticker in your class.